# The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: django, pycharm

Никак не получается запустить Django в PyCharm. Выбивает ошибку. Хотя в `Settings` есть ключ.

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
Stopping epostman_gunicorn_1 ... 
Aborting on container exit...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: возможно в local_settings обнулили SECRET_KEY

Answer (score 2):

Гугл знает несколько вариантов:

**Вариант №1:**

Циклическая зависимость между модулем/классом, загруженным в `settings`, и самим модулем `settings`.

**Вариант №2:**

Добавить переменную окружения. В файлах: `manage.py` или `wsgi.py` добавить строку:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings.local")
```

**Вариант №3:**

Удалить файлы `.pyc` из проекта.

[Источник информации на англ.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19128540/6146442)